# CardView not showing content eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-support-library, android-cardview

I am using `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` to show `ImageView` with two `TextView`'s in `RecyclerView` but card view not showing the content(showing only blank white cards) when the screen orientation is vertical, on the other hand it is showing content when orientation is landscape.

When I run the same project from AndroidStudio there is no problem everything works fine.

I don't understand what is problem out there, is there problem with eclipse?

Please see the code below,

PostListFragment

```
public class PostListFragment extends Fragment implements AppConfig {

    private ArrayList<Post> mPostArrayList;
    private PostRecyclerAdapter mPostRecyclerAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    //other declarations

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //removed 
    }

    private void init() {

        // Set up RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRootView
                .findViewById(R.id.mPostListRecyclerView);

        // Setup layout manager for mPostArrayList and column count
        final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
                getActivity());

        // Control orientation of the mPostArrayList
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);

        // Attach layout manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // Listen to the item touching
        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(
                getActivity(),
                new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View itemView, int position) {
                        //some action
                    }
                }));

        mPostArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Bind adapter to recycler
        mPostRecyclerAdapter = new PostRecyclerAdapter(
                getActivity(), mPostArrayList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPostRecyclerAdapter);

    }

    private void getPosts() {

        // Execute async task
        new AsyncPosts().execute(mPostURL);
    }

    public class AsyncPosts extends AsyncTask<Object, String, JSONObject> {
        //no problem with this
    }
}
```

Layout used for PostListFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mParentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mPostListContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/mPostListSwipeRefreshLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/mPostListRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- removed -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is adapter to set the values, 
PostRecyclerAdapter

```
public class PostRecyclerAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<PostRecyclerAdapter.SimpleItemViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Post> post;

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of data store)
    public PostRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Post> items) {

        this.mContext = context;
        this.post = items;
    }

    // Return the size of your data set (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.post.size();
    }

    // Create new items (invoked by the layout manager)
    // Usually involves inflating a layout from XML and returning the holder
    @Override
    public SimpleItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup,
            int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.post_list_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new SimpleItemViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    // Involves populating data into the item through holder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleItemViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        Glide.with(mContext).load(post.get(position).IMG_URL)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder).crossFade(1000)
                .centerCrop().into(viewHolder.mPostListSmallThumbnail);

        viewHolder.mPostListSmallTitle.setText(post.get(position).POST_TITLE);
        viewHolder.mPostListSmallContent
                .setText(post.get(position).POST_CONTENT);

    }

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public final static class SimpleItemViewHolder extends
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView mPostListSmallThumbnail;
        TextView mPostListSmallTitle, mPostListSmallContent;

        public SimpleItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mPostListSmallThumbnail = (ImageView) itemView
                    .findViewById(R.id.mPostListSmallThumbnail);
            mPostListSmallTitle = (TextView) itemView
                    .findViewById(R.id.mPostListSmallTitle);
            mPostListSmallContent = (TextView) itemView
                    .findViewById(R.id.mPostListSmallContent);
        }
    }
}
```

post_list_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mPostListSmallCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="@drawable/card_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/blog_card_radius"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:contentPadding="@dimen/blog_card_radius">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mPostListSmallThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/blog_image_thumb_dim"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/blog_image_thumb_dim"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_placeholder"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_thumbnail_placeholder" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mPostListSmallTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/post_list_margin_left"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/post_list_margin_right"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mPostListSmallThumbnail"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mPostListSmallThumbnail"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="2"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mPostListSmallContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mPostListSmallThumbnail"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mPostListSmallTitle"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mPostListSmallTitle"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mPostListSmallTitle"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mPostListSmallTitle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mPostListSmallTitle"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here is post_list_item for landscape layout
land/post_list_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mPostListSmallCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/blog_card_margin_landscape"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/blog_card_margin_landscape"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/blog_card_radius"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mPostListSmallThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/blog_image_thumb_dim"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/blog_image_thumb_dim"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_thumbnail_placeholder" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mPostListSmallTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/post_list_margin_left"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/post_list_margin_right"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mPostListSmallThumbnail"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mPostListSmallThumbnail"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="2"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mPostListSmallContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mPostListSmallThumbnail"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mPostListSmallTitle"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mPostListSmallTitle"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mPostListSmallTitle"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mPostListSmallTitle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mPostListSmallTitle"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: `When I run the same project from AndroidStudio there is no problem everything works fine.` What is the issue?

Comment: When I run the project from **Eclipse** the card view is not showing content, all other things works fine

Comment: You shouldn't be using Eclipse anyways. ADT is deprecated.